# C++ Instance variable/pointer to an array in the heap

Tags: c++, arrays, instance-variables

I have an dynamic array of structures.  When I say dynamic, I mean that the number of elements can vary from each time the program is ran.  After having difficulty trying to use the instance variable as an array, I've been having *incompatible types* problems.  Is there any other methods?

I have this structure:

```
struct movie
  {
    int rank;
    string title;
    string distributor;
    string weekend;
    string total;  
} ;
```

I have this class header file :

```
class ReadFile{

public:
    ifstream moviesFile;
    movie movies[];  

    ReadFile(string);
    movie handleLine(string);
    string getString(vector<char>);

};
```

This is how I'm trying to instantiate the *movies* instance variable:

```
//Some code
movie temparray[linecount];
//temparray is filled with various movie structures.
movies = temparray;
```

This is when I get my error.  How would I accomplish my task of instantiating my movies array.  Thankyou!

Comment: While formatting the question instead of using HTML tags, select the code and press CTRL+K to have it correctly formatted.

Comment: `ReadFile` as the name of a (non-functor) class sounds somewhat suspect. Well-designed classes usually represent nouns, not verbs.

Answer (score 4):

Arrays are non-modifiable lvalues so you cannot assign to them

So `movies = temparray;` is illegal

In C++ it is always recommended that you use a `std::vector` instead to C-style arrays

```
//....
public:
    ifstream moviesFile;
    std::vector<movie> movies;  

//....

//Some code
 movie temparray[linecount];
 movies.assign(temparray, temparray+linecount);
```

Comment: Lol, that makes sense!  I was trying to make things more complicated then they should be!  Thanks a lot!

Comment: For this case, yes, `std::vector` would probably be better, but it isn't _always_ recommended over C-style arrays...

Answer (score 1):

You can not define arrays of unknown size in C++, use `std::vector<movie> movies;` to create a dynamic array.